# airflow 1.9 to 1.10 upgrade and now I'm getting empty logs in the UI

Tags: airflow

I recently upgraded from airflow 1.9 to 1.10 and performed the following commands:

- airflow upgradedb
- changed all my celery config names mentioned [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md)
- export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes
- added: log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ execution_date.strftime("%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%M:%%S") }}/{{ try_number }}.log to my config

Jobs seem to be running fine, but when I click logs don't appear in DAG task nodes.

[image]

I opened my network tab and a request to the following url is returning this JSON

[$AIRFLOW_URL/ariflow/get_logs_with_metadata?dag_id=xxxx&task_id=xxxxx&execution_date=2018-09-09T23%3A03%3A10.585986%2B00%3A00&try_number=1&metadata=null](http://$AIRFLOW_URL/ariflow/get_logs_with_metadata?dag_id=xxxx&task_id=xxxxx&execution_date=2018-09-09T23%3A03%3A10.585986%2B00%3A00&try_number=1&metadata=null)

```
{"error":true,"message":["Task log handler file.task does not support read logs.\n'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'\n"],"metadata":{"end_of_log":true}}
```

Additionally there is a 404 request to get js/form-1.0.0.js. Any advice on extra steps to get logs reworking?

I can confirm that logs are showing up in the logs directory for tasks on the airflow server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg

I previously had

```
task_log_reader = file.task
```

and changed it to:

```
task_log_reader = task
```

As well I added:

```
log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}}}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}}}/{{ try_number }}.log
log_processor_filename_template = {{ filename }}.log
```

Comment: Changing the first configuration fixed it for me as well, thanks!

Comment: I wish the documentation for the configuration file would provide what the available options are.  My biggest frustration with Airflow in my current project is that you have to dig forever in the sourcecode from github to figure things out.  Above is a great example.  What other attributes are in the ti object?  and what else can we do for formatting the filename template?  If you introduce a new feature, throw the community a bone and let us know what else you can do with this.